# Node js PgSQL promise not return value from query

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I've followed by PgSql Node js docs and try to use query with Promise but it's not working, but works fine with callback...
How i send query

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';
import { dbConnectLink } from '../../config';

const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: dbConnectLink,
})

let query = (text, params) => {pool.query(text, params)}

export default {
    query
}
```

and then i use

```
import  db  from '../db';

db.query('SELECT NOW() as now', (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err.stack)
            } else {
              console.log(res.rows[0])
            }
})
```

it works fine and get result as '{ now: 2018-11-30T13:32:15.536Z }'
and when i use promise

```
db.query('SELECT NOW() as now')
        .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0]))
        .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```

it throws > 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'

what wrong with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use brackets:

```
let query = (text, params) => pool.query(text, params)
```

The difference is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Basic_syntax).